# Filtering DataGrid bound to ViewSource from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, datagrid

I seem to be having an issue with binding to a datagrid using WPF and Entity Framework.

To make it simple, I have a Database first application. I want to display a list of monsters from the monster table and then filter based on the name. In winforms, I can do this, but Datagrids in WPF seem to be throwing me through the loop

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="1000" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:adventuretime x:Key="adventuretime"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="monstersViewSource" Source="{Binding Monsters, Source={StaticResource adventuretime}}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource monstersViewSource}">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="972"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="monstersDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,37,10,10" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="monsterIDColumn" Binding="{Binding MonsterID}" Header="Monster ID" IsReadOnly="True" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sizeColumn" Binding="{Binding Size}" Header="Size" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="monstertypeColumn" Binding="{Binding Monstertype}" Header="Monstertype" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="alignmentColumn" Binding="{Binding Alignment}" Header="Alignment" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="aCColumn" Binding="{Binding AC}" Header="AC" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="hPColumn" Binding="{Binding HP}" Header="HP" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="strengthColumn" Binding="{Binding Strength}" Header="Strength" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dexterityColumn" Binding="{Binding Dexterity}" Header="Dexterity" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="constitutionColumn" Binding="{Binding Constitution}" Header="Constitution" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="intelligenceColumn" Binding="{Binding Intelligence}" Header="Intelligence" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="wisdomColumn" Binding="{Binding Wisdom}" Header="Wisdom" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="charismaColumn" Binding="{Binding Charisma}" Header="Charisma" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="savesColumn" Binding="{Binding Saves}" Header="Saves" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="skillColumn" Binding="{Binding Skill}" Header="Skill" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="immuneColumn" Binding="{Binding Immune}" Header="Immune" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="sensesColumn" Binding="{Binding Senses}" Header="Senses" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="languagesColumn" Binding="{Binding Languages}" Header="Languages" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="passiveColumn" Binding="{Binding Passive}" Header="Passive" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="speedColumn" Binding="{Binding Speed}" Header="Speed" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="crColumn" Binding="{Binding cr}" Header="cr" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        adventuretime adventuretime;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            adventuretime = ((adventuretime)(this.FindResource("adventuretime")));

            // Load data into the table Monsters. You can modify this code as needed.
            adventuretimeTableAdapters.MonstersTableAdapter adventuretimeMonstersTableAdapter = new adventuretimeTableAdapters.MonstersTableAdapter();
            adventuretimeMonstersTableAdapter.Fill(adventuretime.Monsters);
            CollectionViewSource monstersViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("monstersViewSource")));
            monstersViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        }
    }
```

The application loads, and I get the data from the table, so that's great.

I just have no idea how manipulate the data in there.

doing something like dataGrid.ItemSource = linq query doesn't seem to be an option. So I am not sure how to bind it so I can filter on the textbox contents.

can anyone point me in the right direction? I've been looking for the last two days but nothing seems to match what my application is generating when I drag and drop the datagrid to the WPF designer

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CollectionViewSource.View has a Filter property that is a Predicate<object>. Use that to filter.

To tie it into your textbox, assuming you want to filter on 'Name', add an event handler to the textbox for the TextChanged event. Like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="972"
    TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
```

In the code behind, add the TextBox_TextChanged method. Define it as this:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    CollectionViewSource monstersViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("monstersViewSource")));

    if (tb == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
    {
        monstersViewSource.View.Filter = null;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string txt = tb.Text;
        monstersViewSource.View.Filter = item =>
        {
            Monster m = item as Monster;
            if (m != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(m.Name) && m.Name.Contains(txt))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
    }
}
```

The filter uses Contains instead of equals so it will filter out anything that doesn't contain the textbox text. Like "dra" will match "dragon" and "drake".

BTW - I don't see any entity-framework in this question.

**EDIT:**

I guess DataTable doesn't support filtering like that... try this instead then. You may need to change the DataSet1 to whatever your DataSet is. And maybe the % to * in the LIKE statement?

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    CollectionViewSource monstersViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("monstersViewSource")));

    if (tb == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
    {
        DataSet1.MonstersDataTable dt = monstersViewSource.Source as DataSet1.MonstersDataTable;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        string txt = tb.Text;

        DataSet1.MonstersDataTable dt = monstersViewSource.Source as DataSet1.MonstersDataTable;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", txt);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Is this any faster?

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as TextBox;
    CollectionViewSource monstersViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("monstersViewSource")));

    if (tb == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tb.Text))
    {
        var cv = monstersViewSource.View as BindingListCollectionView;
        cv.CustomFilter = null;
    }
    else
    {
        string txt = tb.Text;

        var cv = monstersViewSource.View as BindingListCollectionView;
        cv.CustomFilter = string.Format("Name like '%{0}%'", txt);
    }
}
```

If not any faster, I think you may need to actually use entity-framework and the first TextBox_TextChanged method instead of datasets, dataadapters and datatables to get it to filter faster.

Comment: Thanks for the help, looks like I get a "Specified method is not supported." error on the View.Filter when I run the app. Build is fine though.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Although it's god awful slow. So I think  search button is in order.

Comment: Glad it works. Not so glad that its slow! Just how many items do you have? I had 6 in my test case I made for you.

Comment: ummm it will range from 6 to > 1k rows per table. (lots of 1-M relationships in this database) Because it's d&d. So the filtering on each time the text changes might not even be needed? Not sure of the best design aspect since I'm mostly jut learning right now.

Comment: Try my edit 2. Filtering when the txt changes may not be needed but it shouldn't be that slow even with 1k items. Computers are fast, usually.

Comment: I just tried it with Edit 1 and Edit 2 after adding 2165 more items. Both methods are instantly filtering on my system (i7 3.5 ghz, 32 gb ram). Maybe it's just my computer is fast? Try a release build or at least start without debugging?

Comment: It might be my system. I will give it a go tonight or tomorrow and report back,

Comment: It did speeds things up considerably on my POS work laptop, so I think I should be good. Going to look into setting it up on my PC.